# C++: Why must private functions be declared?

Tags: c++, class, function, private, declaration

Why do classes in C++ have to declare their private functions? Has it actual technical reasons (what is its role at compile time) or is it simply for consistency's sake?

Comment: Are you asking why the functions themselves have to be declared, or are you asking why you have to say `private` for those functions?

Comment: @GManNickG I think the first one.

Comment: @GManNickG 1st one. I just don't know why other classes including my header have to know about its private functions

Comment: @Ancurio they don't. That's info for the class itself - i.e. the class knows that `foo` is a member and has access to other members.

Comment: `private` and `virtual` are orthogonal concepts. The fact that a function is `private` does not imply that it is not `virtual` (as a matter of fact there is a whole idiom around having *only* `private` `virtual` and `public` non-virtual member functions), so yes, the presence affect the vtable.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas good point. I actually didn't know virtual private functions could be overridden in child classes and have their base classes call the new version without exposing callability(is this even a word?)

Comment: @Ancurio: The word you want is 'accessibility'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I asked why private functions had to be declared at all, as they don't add anything (neither object size nor vtable entry) for other translation units to know

If you think about it, this is similar to declaring some functions `static` in a file. It's not visible from the outside, but it is important for the compiler itself. The compiler wants to know the signature of the function before it can use it. That's why you declare functions in the first place. **Remember that C++ compilers are one pass, which means everything has to be declared before it is used.<sup>1</sup>**

From the programmer's point of view, declaring private functions is still not completely useless. Imagine 2 classes, one of which is the `friend` of the other. The friendzoned class<sup>2</sup> would need to know how the privates of that class look like, (This discussion is getting weird) otherwise they can't use it.

As to why exactly C++ was designed in this way, I would first say there is the historical reason: the fact that you can't slice a struct in C, was adopted by C++ so you can't slice a class (and adopted by other languages branched from C++, too). I'd also guess that it's about simplicity: Imagine how difficult it would be to devise a method of compilation in which you can split the class among different header files, let your source files know about it, and prevent others from adding stuff to your class.

A final note is that, `private` functions *can* affect vtable size. That is, if they are `virtual`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Actually not entirely. If you have inline functions in the class, they can refer to functions later defined in the same class. But probably the idea started from single pass and this exception later added to it.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>It's inlined member functions in particular.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I'm used to hiding implementation in C by using static C functions, that's why I'd have expected to simply declare (before any implementation) private functions inside the cpp apart from the rest, just like static declarations in C

Comment: @Ancurio, even though what you say absolutely makes sense, unfortunately there is no support from C++ to slice a class definition in two.

Comment: Having the signatures declared before usage is only vaguely related to why they have to be in the class itself. The friendzoned class doesn't need to know the privates of the other, it's member function definitions need to know the privates.  That can also come later/outside the class.  And there are interesting things you can do with templates which could be said to slice a class definition in two.  Which reminds me, class definitions with inline functions _are_ two-pass, not one pass. Thats why you can use members/functions in a member function definition _before_ that member is declared.

Comment: @MooingDuck, indeed, I am aware that the pass on the class declaration itself is not one-pass. However, this still applies since most of the times you define the functions outside the class, after the class has been declared. Like I said in a comment above, it would have been nice if you could put the declarations of private members/functions in an internal header file, but there is no direct support for it. (You can always have a `void *internal;`, but that's just a workaround).

Comment: @Shahbaz: So, as the OP asked, why is there no support for it?

Comment: @MooingDuck, besides the historical reason (the fact that you can't slice a `struct` in C, was adopted by C++ so you can't slice a `class` (and adopted by other languages branched from C++, too)), I'd guess it's about simplicity. Imagine how difficult it would be to devise a plan so you can split the class among different header files, let everyone know about it, and prevent others from adding stuff to your class.

Answer (score 20):

You have to declare all members in the definition of the class itself so that the compiler knows which functions are *allowed* to be members.  Otherwise, a second programmer could (accidentally?) come along and add members, make mistakes, and violate your object's guarantees, causing undefined behavior and/or random crashes.

Comment: I think you just described Python classes =)

Answer (score 3):

There's a combination of concerns, but:

- C++ doesn't let you re-open a class to declare new members in it after its initial definition.
- C++ doesn't let you have different definitions of a class in different translation units that combine to form a program.

Therefore:

- Any private member functions that the .cpp file wants declared in the class need to be defined in the .h file, which every user of the class sees too.

From the POV of practical binary compatibility: as David says in a comment, private `virtual` functions affect the size and layout of the vtable of this class and any classes that use it as a base. So the compiler needs to know about them even when compiling code that can't call them.

Could C++ have been invented differently, to allow the .cpp file to reopen the class and add certain kinds of additional member functions, with the implementation required to   arrange that this doesn't break binary compatibility? Could the one definition rule be relaxed, to allow definitions that differ in certain ways? For example, static member functions and non-virtual non-static member functions.

Probably yes to both. I don't think there's any technical obstacle, although the current ODR is *very* strict about what makes a definition "different" (and hence is very generous to implementations in allowing binary incompatibilities between very similar-looking definitions). I think the text to introduce this kind of exception to the rule would be complex.

Ultimately it might come down to, "the designers wanted it that way", or it might be that someone tried it and encountered an obstacle that I haven't thought of.

Comment: The current modules proposals have solutions to the privacy issue, simply because they add another "layer" or "room" of visibility: The class itself, the module, the "outer code". `private` will then simply not leak outside the module definition, and the compiler can still know about everything.

Comment: "_C++ doesn't let you re-open a class to declare new members in it after its initial definition._" That is not correct: 14.7.3 **Explicit specialization** `[temp.expl.spec]` "An explicit specialization of any of the following: (...) — member class template of a class or class template
— member function template of a class or class template
can be declared by a declaration (...)" "An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template."

Comment: @curiousguy: not sure I follow you. I don't think that a specialization of a member template is a "new member", since the template is the member. I may be wrong. If I am wrong then of course templates are an exception to what I was saying, since as well as specializing member templates outside the class you can of course also *instantiate* member templates outside the class. In neither case do I think that the class has been "re-opened", and I don't think it helps the questioner.

Comment: @SteveJessop A template definition describes a potentially infinite set of specialisations. You can view a function template declaration as the "potential" declaration of an infinite set of functions, and a member template declaration as the "potential" declaration of an infinite set of members. You can count a new member template explicit specialisation as a new member or not. My point is that 1) a member template explicit specialisation is declared outside the class definition 2) its body is the body of a member function (if it is a function template).

Comment: (...) "_you can of course also instantiate member templates outside the class._" Yes, but you cannot rewrite their definition. "_In neither case do I think that the class has been "re-opened",_" With an explicit specialisation, the class can be "re-opened".

Comment: You *could* view it as 'the "potential" declaration of an infinite set of members', but as I say above I believe it is incorrect to do so. I believe there is one member, which is the template. Adding specializations to a function template never affects whether or not the template is selected by the lookup rules, it only affects how the instantiation is generated. Which is why in general you should overload function templates rather than specializing them, although in the case of class members you have no choice once the class is defined, since it cannot be re-opened to add overloads.

Comment: Anyway, we're arguing about the proper the definition of the phrase "re-open a class to add new members", which is irrelevant to the question. With the meaning of the phrase that I have defined in these comments (specializing a member template is not "re-opening to add new members") the statement I made in my answer is true. With your definition of the phrase, the statement is false but could be made true by adding extra weasel-wording. Both ways the answer to the question is, "because if you leave the private members out of the class definition there's no mechanism add them later".

Comment: I am not sure a philosophical discussion about "what **a** member is" is needed here. A template member cannot be a virtual function. So **this is not a general tool for adding "later" arbitrary members to a class definition**. A template function member is much like a friend function template, it has access to members. The "re-opening" is limited to writing code with access to private members.

Answer (score 2):

The access level does not affect visibility. Private functions are visible to external code and may be selected by overload resolution (which would then result in an access violoation error):

```
class A {
    void F(int i) {}
public:
    void F(unsigned i) {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.F(1); // error, void A::F(int) is private
}
```

Imagine the confusion when this works:

```
class A {
public:
    void F(unsigned i) {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.F(1);
}

// add private F overload to A
void A::F(int i) {}
```

But changing it to the first code causes overload resolution to select a different function. And what about the following example?

```
class A {
public:
    void F(unsigned i) {}
};

// add private F overload to A
void A::F(int i) {}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.F(1);
}
```

Or here's another example of this going wrong:

```
// A.h
class A {
public:
    void g() { f(1); }
    void f(unsigned);
};

// A_private_interface.h
class A;
void A::f(int);

// A.cpp
#include "A_private_interface.h"
#include "A.h"

void A::f(int) {}
void A::f(unsigned) {}

// main.cpp
#include "A.h"

int main() {
    A().g();
}
```

Comment: Eh, this seems to only point out that overloading rules would need to change.

Comment: @GManNickG To take visibility into account and not select inaccessible methods? C++ has good reason for the way it works. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644461/c-constructor-overloading-private-and-public

Comment: I don't think the overloading rules would need to take accessibility into account. They'd probably just have to be defined to only take into account member functions which are declared before the point of use -- so if your private member function is in the class definition then it stops `a.F(1)` compiling in client code, and if it's added only in `A.cpp` then it doesn't affect client code but does affect the .cpp. This is already how namespaces work (if you add more overloads, they might get selected). There's some complexity required, for example what happens with two-phase lookup.

Comment: @SteveJessop Of course that could be done, but I think it'd be quite a significant change. For example, currently the scope for class members is the entire class, even before the class member is declared. I don't think the complexity is warranted because it only solves one special case of the underlying problem that is the C++ compilation model, and there are already workarounds that solve that special case.

Comment: I agree that the change isn't needed, I'm just imagining the confusion as instructed, and I don't think it's all that confusing. Class members declared in the class definition could of course continue to be visible anywhere in the class as before. Members added by this hypothetical new mechanism would have different visibility, since that's the entire purpose of the new mechanism.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't know, that sounds pretty bad to me. For example it's adding new opportunities to violate the ODR without anything obviously being defined twice. Anyway, don't imagine your own confusion, imagine the confusion of someone that isn't already perfectly at home with things like SFINAE and two-phase name lookup.

Comment: With c++11, overloads can be explicitly deleted with `= delete` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that in C++ friends can access your privates. For friends to access them, friends have to know about them.

Comment: @Neal: Well... that's the friggin *purpose* of `friend`s.

Answer (score 0):

Private members of a class are still members of the class, so they must be declared, as the implementation of other public members might depend on that private method. Declaring them will allow the compiler to understand a call to that function as a member function call.

If you have a method that only is used int the `.cpp` file and does not depend on direct access to other private members of the class, consider moving it to an anonymous namespace. Then, it does not need to be declared in the header file.

Comment: yes, but _why does the spec say they must be declared_?  You didnt answer the question.  There s already rules saying functions must be declared before calling, so that's not it.  (the namespace tip is a good one though)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reason on why private functions must be declared.

*First Compile Time Error Checks*

the point of access modifiers is to catch certain classes (no pun intended) of programming errors at compile time. Private functions are functions that, if someone called them from outside the class, that would be a bug, and you want to know about it as early as possible.

*Second Casting and Inheritance*

Taken from the C++ standard:

3 [ Note: A member of a private base class might be inaccessible as an inherited member name, but accessible directly. Because of the rules on pointer conversions (4.10) and explicit casts (5.4), a conversion from a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to an inaccessible base class might be ill-formed if an implicit conversion is used, but well-formed if an explicit cast is used.

*3rd Friends*

Friends show each other there privates. A private method can be call by another class that is a friend.

*4th General Sanity and Good Design*

Ever worked on a project with another 100 developers. Having a standard and a general set of rule helps maintain maintainable. declaring something private has a specific meaning to everyone else in the group.

Also this flows into good OO design principles. What to expose and what not

Comment: That's not want Ancurio wants to know. He wonders why we can't (some) keep private functions as a *secret* in the first place. You can't call a function that you don't know about.

Comment: the compiler needs to know that its private. so it can kick out a compile time warning when someone else try to call it...nothing is ever really a secret

Comment: @nate_weldon that's true, but if private non-virtual functions weren't declared in a public header file (and therefore documentation) in the first place, no one would attempt to call it. Except maybe for myself... in which case that warning (isn't it an error actually?) does make sense.

Comment: accept for friends ...because friends show each other their privates

Comment: this also had to deal with how things are cast to other types

Comment: from the standard 

3 [ Note: A member of a private base class might be inaccessible as an inherited member name, but accessible directly.
Because of the rules on pointer conversions (4.10) and explicit casts (5.4), a conversion from a pointer to a derived class
to a pointer to an inaccessible base class might be ill-formed if an implicit conversion is used, but well-formed if an
explicit cast is used.

Comment: @nate_weldon: useful information belongs in answers not comments.  Comments can and are deleted without warning.